# FBX import not rendering textures, though look linked properly

Tags: texturing, armature, import

I'm very new to blender. I have a fbx file and some accompanying png texture files. The file has a rigged animated armature. It looks like the textures are linked properly and have a bunch of configuration however they are not being applied to the model.

[image: model and texture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 Fixes : The first would be to enable textured solid , By opening the right tab ( use N )

[image]

The second is enable the texture mode , above the solid view. [! You have to have lights in the scene so everything is visible )

[image]

third would be using the UV / Image editor

[image]

[image]

Also , in the texture tab ( next to the materials tab ), make sure you have set UV co - ordinant.