# Loading obj file, loosing texture

Tags: texturing

I am fairly new to Blender. I downloaded that file:
[https://free3d.com/3d-model/salmon-44387.html]

and tried to import it in Blender. It works great but I am losing all the textures. I googled around 
https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?220278-Imported-OBJ-file-no-textures

[FBX import not rendering textures, though look linked properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23058/fbx-import-not-rendering-textures-though-look-linked-properly)

but could not find a satisfying answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: You can use the search box at the top of the page to get results like these: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=imported+.obj+texture

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos nope that a dup of that at all. This is *importing* not exporting. completely different issue.

Comment: This is how to do it in the [cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/65918/2217) and here is [blender internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97190/2217).